# asp.net Gridview check selected index client side

Tags: gridview

how can i do this client side, 
OnClientClick of the btnYes will return false if the gridview selected index < 0;

```
protected void btnYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (gvCourseDetails.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
        ClientScriptManager scriptManager = Page.ClientScript;
        scriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alertmessage",
                       "<script>alert('Select a course above first');</script>");
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GridView's selected index will not change without a postback anyway, so you can evaluate it only once on the server side (on page_load or btnYes prerender, etc). It is almost meaningless on the client side.

```
if (gvCourseDetails.SelectedIndex == -1)
{
   btnYes.OnClientClick = "alert('Select a course above first'); return false;";
}
else
{
   btnYes.OnClientClick = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you can declare a public variable and store the SelectedIndex in it then call it from the client side script but you will need to post back the page:

```
public int selectedIndex = 0;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
selectedIndex = gvCourseDetails.SelectedIndex;
}
```

//and here the client side script

```
function CheckSelectedIndex()
{
   if(<%= selectedIndex%> == -1)
   {
       // type you code
   }
}
```